# Is there any way to get Virtual Machine object by just instance name without resource Group in AzureRm in java API?

Tags: java, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

```
VirtualMachineGetResponse get(String resourceGroupName, String vmName) throws IOException, ServiceException, URISyntaxException;
```

From VirtualMachineGetResponse, I can get VirtualMachine. 
Is there any way to get VirtualMachine object by just giving instanceId as above code snippet expects resourceGroupName and instanceName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any way to get VM object with only instance name in ARM for any languages. It's depended on Azure REST API [`Get` for Virtual Machines in ARM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines#VirtualMachines_Get), and the Java API just wrap it.

The REST API `GET` request for Virtual Machines in ARM, as below.

> GET /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}?api-version=2016-03-30[&$expand]

Besides `subscriptionId` required for authentication, the parameters `resourceGroupName` & `vmName` are required in the api uri.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by how ARM works, I don't think there is a way to do that at all (doesn't matter what language\tool you are using).

What you can do, is get the list off ALL vm's and filter the one you need.